# Neo4j's online exercises:Movie Database - Finding 'friends' and 'paths' question

Tags: neo4j

so I'm following this guide/exercise on neo4j about a movie database, where I'm also using the same data from there([link here](http://guides.neo4j.com/intro-neo4j-exercises/05.html)).
Now my problem is trying to find the co-co actors of a particular person. eg Tom Hanks.
co co actors are all the actors who have acted in a movie with a co-actor of Tom Hanks, but have not acted in a movie with Hanks
Now looking at the solutions for exercise 5.4 from the link, my code should look something like this right?
I run the code, but there's no output/records

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN*2]->(a2:Actor)    
WHERE a.name = "Tom Hanks"
AND NOT((a)-[:ACTED_IN]-(a2))
RETURN a2.name AS `co-co-actors`
```

or maybe like this?

```
MATCH (a:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a2:Actor), 
    (a2:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a3:Actor)
WHERE a.name = 'Tom Hanks'
RETURN a3.name AS `co-co-actors`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close!
First, you can indeed fetch the co-actors of Tom Hanks:

```
(tom:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActor:Person)
```

Then, you want to find the co-actors of Tom Hanks co-actors:

```
(coCoActor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActor)
```

But you want to make sure that these "co-co-actors" never played in any movie with Tom Hanks:

```
WHERE NOT (coCoActor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(tom)
```

The whole query becomes then:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActor:Person),
      (coCoActor:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(coActor)
WHERE NOT (coCoActor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(tom)
RETURN coCoActor.name AS `co-co-actor`
```

For instance, Jack Nicholson seems to be a co-co-actor of Tom Hanks.
Let's check:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"}), (jack:Person {name: "Jack Nicholson"})
RETURN shortestPath((tom)-[*]-(jack))
```

[image: shortest path between Tom Hanks and Jack Nicholson]

It seems to be the case, hurray!

Comment: Thats an awesome explanation. Thanks a lot!!! So if a few co-co actors of Tom Hanks appear in multiple movies with Tom hanks co-actors, so for instance Jack nicholas is a co-co actor of Tom Hanks  who has acted in more than one movie with Tom hanks co actors. Then we can say that they have multiple paths between Tom and Jack. How would I sort a list according to the number of paths between the two of them? God, I confused my self here a few times. But does this make sense?

Comment: This is the code I wrote in descending order.                         
        `MATCH (tom:Person)-[r1:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[r2:ACTED_IN]-(a2:Person)- 
          [r3:ACTED_IN]->(m2:Movie)<-[: ACTED_IN]-(a3:Person)
          WHERE tom.name = 'Tom Hanks'
          RETURN a3.name,count(m2) as NO_Paths order by NO_Paths desc.                       Sorry not sure how to format it in code in the comments